# NSCoding encoding and decoding UITouchProperties in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nscoding

Encoding and decoding UITouchProperties

[image]

I am getting an error of "Cannot convert UITouchProperties to expected argument type AnyObject".

One solution could be to turn it into a String for encoding and then back when decoding, but the app crashes upon decoding. I'm not quite sure how the syntax would look for that scenario, so I'm not sure if I tested that correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do this was to encode, for example, "estimated properties" as an int by saving estimated properties.rawValue

then when decoding i did estimatedProperties = UITouchProperties(decode estimated properties .rawValue as Int)

seems to working fine now